# NotOneValueFound: Expected one value, found 0 sklean 1.02 updated to sklean 1.2.2 then code broke

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

**problem**

Defining models for OneVsRestClassifier and OneVsOneClassifier for SVC kernel='rbf'. Code was running fine until I updated sklearn from 1.02 to 1.2.2

I first perform a min max scaler to transform the training data, working code.
Perform standard scaling. Then select with iloc[] the pixels range. Then select the y label for y response. Then create the OneVsRestClassifier and OneVsOneClassifier model classifiers to execute on SCV with kernel choice of RBF, all working code before upgrading to sklearn 1.2.2.

What is the compiler complaining regarding 'A task has failed to un-serialize'?

**Code**

```
train = train.loc[(train['label'] > 1) & (train['label'] < 4)]

y = train['label']
    
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, y, test_size=0.60, random_state=42)

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_train_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train.iloc[:, 2:786])
X = X_train.iloc[:, 2:786]
y = X_train['label']

X_train = X_train.drop(['label'], axis=1)
svc_RBF_OVR_model = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='rbf'))
svc_RBF_OVO_model = OneVsOneClassifier(SVC(kernel='rbf'))

param_grid = {
    "estimator__C": [1,2,4,8],
    "estimator__kernel": ["poly","rbf"],
    "estimator__degree":[1, 2, 3, 4]
}
# Tune the hyperparameters using GridSearchCV
svc_RBF_OVR_grid_param = RandomizedSearchCV(svc_RBF_OVR_model, param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=3, error_score="raise")
svc_RBF_OVO_grid_param = RandomizedSearchCV(svc_RBF_OVO_model, param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=3, error_score="raise")

svc_RBF_OVR_model_fit = svc_RBF_OVR_grid_param.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train) 
svc_RBF_OVO_model_fit = svc_RBF_OVO_grid_param.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
```

**Error message trace**

```
exception calling callback for <Future at 0x7fc951a564f0 state=finished raised BrokenProcessPool>
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 391, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 122, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_FuncWrapper' on <module 'sklearn.utils.fixes' from '/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py'>
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/_base.py", line 625, in _invoke_callbacks
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 359, in __call__
    ###############################################################################
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 792, in dispatch_next
    def _effective_n_jobs(self):
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 859, in dispatch_one_batch
    # queue, _ready_batches, that is looked-up prior to re-consuming
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 777, in _dispatch
    if self.timeout is not None and not self._backend.supports_timeout:
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 531, in apply_async
    "DASK_DISTRIBUTED__WORKER__DAEMON=False\n"
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/reusable_executor.py", line 177, in submit
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 1102, in submit
    worker_exit_lock.acquire()
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.
Unexpected exception formatting exception. Falling back to standard exception
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 391, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 122, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_FuncWrapper' on <module 'sklearn.utils.fixes' from '/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py'>
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3442, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "/var/folders/zl/zh18_1yx1b74nzd6kt936mlh0000gn/T/ipykernel_67007/2196762926.py", line 20, in <module>
    svc_RBF_OVR_model_fit = svc_RBF_OVR_grid_param.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 891, in fit
    self.refit, refit_metric, results
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 1766, in _run_search
    def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 838, in evaluate_candidates
    if len(out) < 1:
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1054, in __call__
    if hasattr(pre_dispatch, 'endswith'):
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 933, in retrieve
    self._print('Done %3i tasks      | elapsed: %s',
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 542, in wrap_future_result
    elif not (self.in_main_thread() or self.nesting_level == 0):
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 446, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/_base.py", line 625, in _invoke_callbacks
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 359, in __call__
    ###############################################################################
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 792, in dispatch_next
    def _effective_n_jobs(self):
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 859, in dispatch_one_batch
    # queue, _ready_batches, that is looked-up prior to re-consuming
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 777, in _dispatch
    if self.timeout is not None and not self._backend.supports_timeout:
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 531, in apply_async
    "DASK_DISTRIBUTED__WORKER__DAEMON=False\n"
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/reusable_executor.py", line 177, in submit
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 1102, in submit
    worker_exit_lock.acquire()
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2057, in showtraceback
    stb = self.InteractiveTB.structured_traceback(
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1118, in structured_traceback
    return FormattedTB.structured_traceback(
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1012, in structured_traceback
    return VerboseTB.structured_traceback(
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 865, in structured_traceback
    formatted_exception = self.format_exception_as_a_whole(etype, evalue, etb, number_of_lines_of_context,
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 818, in format_exception_as_a_whole
    frames.append(self.format_record(r))
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 736, in format_record
    result += ''.join(_format_traceback_lines(frame_info.lines, Colors, self.has_colors, lvals))
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stack_data/utils.py", line 145, in cached_property_wrapper
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stack_data/core.py", line 698, in lines
    pieces = self.included_pieces
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stack_data/utils.py", line 145, in cached_property_wrapper
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stack_data/core.py", line 649, in included_pieces
    pos = scope_pieces.index(self.executing_piece)
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stack_data/utils.py", line 145, in cached_property_wrapper
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stack_data/core.py", line 628, in executing_piece
    return only(
  File "/Users/matthew/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/executing/executing.py", line 164, in only
    raise NotOneValueFound('Expected one value, found 0')
executing.executing.NotOneValueFound: Expected one value, found 0
```

Comment: If you need data, let me know, its the standard training data set, (train.csv), has 785 columns. The first column, called "label", from the Digits Recognizer Kaggle competition

Comment: Have you checked release notes for sklearn versions between 1.0 and 1.2.2? Scikit-learn often breaks backwards compatibility between major version updates.

Comment: No I have not. Is there a way to back out of 1.2.2? I don't have time to fix as I have a project that needs this by week end

Comment: Why not just `pip install scikit-learn==1.0.2`?

Comment: I think I will do that

Answer (score 1):

error is coming from RandomizedSearchCV most likly with `n_jobs` parameter

try testing it with it `-1 or None` and see if it makes any difference

Comment: work again, just have a UserWarning: The memmapped array

Comment: does anyone who how to supress this UserWaring: memmapped array. I have import warnings set and working but not for this UserWarning

Comment: memmapped array seems to be a numpy warning you can use

`np.seterr(all="ignore")`  see if it works